# Why are there alignment boundaries larger than 4?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

What i don't understand, is why we have to align data in memory on boundaries larger than 4 bytes since all the other boundaries are multiples of 4. Assuming a CPU can read 4 bytes in a cycle, it will be basically no difference in performance if that data is 8 bytes large and is aligned on a 4 byte / 8 byte / 16 byte, etc.

Comment: What CPU/architecture are you referring to?

Comment: Why do you assume that the CPU reads 4 bytes in a cycle?

Comment: Why are there alignment boundaries larger than 1? ;-) If you can answer that, then you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Marco A: It was just an example. Right now i work with an x64 Intel.

Comment: @user3503828 you can't ask why a CPU works the way it does, without specifying which CPU you're talking about.

Comment: @PeterSchneider From what i understand, having only alignment of 1 would be possible for data to be stored at addresses like 3 or 5. But since 8 , 16, 32 are all multiple of 4 i don't see the reason of aligning data on 8 bytes rather than 4 bytes.

Comment: There are boundaries considerably larger than four for platform-specific reasons. An AS/400, for example, *requires* all pointers reside on a 128bit boundary (and you can only imagine the madness this introduces when you have arrays of structures with nested structures with pointer members). Alignment is very platform specific, so you can't just generalize that four ought to be good enough.

Comment: @user3503828, some x86 instructions require 16 or 32 byte alignment or they crash. Also reading a word (say a 16 byte word) split across a cache lines (64 bytes) or a virtual pages (4096 bytes) can lower performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: x86 CPUs don't read stuff in 4 bytes only, they can read 8 bytes in a cycle or even more with [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) extensions.

But to answer your question "*why are there alignment boundaries multiple than 4*?", assuming a generic architecture (you didn't specify one and [you wrote that x86 was just an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660238/why-are-there-alignment-boundaries-larger-than-4?noredirect=1#comment40098460_25660238)) I'll present a specific case: GPUs.

NVIDIA GPU memory can only be accessed (store/load) if the address is aligned on a multiple of the access size ([PTX ISA ld/st](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/)). There are different kinds of loads and the most performant ones happen when the address is aligned to a multiple of the access size so if you're trying to load a double from memory (8 bytes) you would have (pseudocode):

```
ld.double [48dec] // Works, 8 bytes aligned
ld.double [17dec] // Fails, not 8 bytes aligned
```

in the above case when trying to access (r/w) memory that is not properly aligned the process will actually cause an error. If you want speed you'll have to provide some safety guarantees.

That might answer your question on why alignment boundaries larger than 4 exist in the first place. On such an architecture an access size of 1 is always safe (every address is aligned to 1). That isn't true for every *n*>1.

Comment: Is it safe to say that the alignment gives a hint to the cpu on how much data to read from memory? What i mean is, aligning an INT to 8 bytes is it safe to assume that the cpu would expect that the INT has another 4 bytes after it that are somehow meaningful for that data?

Comment: Again it depends on the architecture but usually it isn't for a "hinting" reason but in the case I posted above you will have an error 'address misaligned' if you don't honor the rule. To achieve a degree of performances and ensure consistency between caching capabilities and other architectural differences these constraints have to be met. It might be mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

When an x86 CPU reads a `double`, it reads 8 bytes in a cycle. When it reads an SSE vector, it reads 16 bytes. When it reads an AVX vector, it reads 32.

When the CPU fetches a cache line from memory, it also reads *at least* 32 bytes.

Your assumption that the CPU reads 4 bytes per cycle is false.

Comment: I'm afraid i didn't state make case clearley. How much it read from the memory was just an example. But let's talk your example. either if it read 8 bytes or 16 or 32 all that data should be aligned on individual boundaries, 8, 16, 32. But since 8, 16, 32 are all multiples of 4 in my current humble understanding of things it should be the same for the cpu if the double for instance, would be aligned on a 4 byte boundary.

Comment: @user3503828: They're also multiples of 2. The fact that Y is a multiple of X just does not matter.